# Problem compiling .tex file with TextStudio in windows 10

Tags: latex, miktex

I usually use overleaf to write latex docs but I need to download a offline editor in order to write text files without internet. I was researching about the best latex editors and I found TextStudio. First I downloaded MikTek and then TextStudio. However, when I try to compile a .tex file in TextStudio appear the next error in a floating window:

*Could not be started Default Compiler.PdfLaTeX:
"C:/Users/3J/Documents/MikTex/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "prueba_trabajo".tex*

And in the editor too:

*Sorry, but C:\Users\3J\Documents\MikTex\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\3J\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
El proceso terminó con error(es)*

If someone know how to install this editor and how to work properly in windows 10 I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

I tried re-installing MikTek and TextStudio, also following some Youtube tutorials but nothig has worked. Also I tried installing latex in vscode but when I tried to install strawberry perl I couldn't because of a problem with a DLL required that I still don't know how to fix.

Comment: Can you show the content of `C:\Users\3J\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log`. As overleaf is very good at hiding error messages, can you try a simple test file instead of your real document, e.g. `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}`?

Comment: (assuming you actually mean `texstudio` and not `textstudio`)

Comment: Yes, I was meaning TexStudio, sorry. I've tried vith a simple test file as you said and has appeared the same error. 

On the other hand, the content of this route is a txt file which says (continue in the next comment):

Sorry, but: Permission denied: path="C:\Users\3J\AppData\Local\Temp\mik75771"

2024-02-26 17:51:19,099+0100 FATAL pdflatex.core - The memory dump file could not be found.
2024-02-26 17:51:19,099+0100 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"

Comment: 2024-02-26 17:51:19,099+0100 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp:697
2024-02-26 17:51:19,099+0100 FATAL pdflatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2024-02-26 17:51:19,100+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2024-02-26 17:51:19,100+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2024-02-26 17:51:19,100+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 697
2024-02-26 17:51:19,103+0100 INFO  pdflatex - this process (12344) finishes with exit code 1

Comment: Ok, so there seems to be a problem with miktex. I'm neither a miktex nor a windows users, but the error sounds a bit similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349479/36296 Maybe some antivirur or similar tool is interfering.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I've tried too many things but my pc was getting into failure, so I decided to format it and now LaTeX installation problem is solved too! Thank you again!

Comment: Very glad to hear your tex installation is now working!